# Relationship between dataprovider in parallel mode and thread parallel "methods" setting

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider

There are two test classes with each having one test method using a datatprovider in parallel mode.

```
public class FirstNg {

    @Test(dataProvider = "dp11", description="f one")
    public void f11(Integer n, String s) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("DP FIR ----" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "----" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    }

    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] dp11() {
        return new Object[][] { new Object[] { 1, "a" }, new Object[] { 2, "b" }, new Object[] { 3, "c" },
                new Object[] { 4, "d" }};
    }

}
```

---

```
public class SecondNg {

    @Test(dataProvider = "dp22", description="f two")
    public void f22(Integer n, String s) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("DP SEC ----" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "----" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    }

    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] dp22() {
        return new Object[][] { new Object[] { 1, "a" }, new Object[] { 2, "b" }, new Object[] { 3, "c" },
                new Object[] { 4, "d" }};
    }       
}
```

The duration of test run is calculated with times determined in BeforeSuite and AterSuite.

**Case 1 - Run without any thread parallel setting.**

```
<suite name="suite" data-provider-thread-count="2"> 
  <test name="test"> 
    <classes> 
      <class name="FirstNg"/> 
      <class name="SecondNg"/> 
    </classes> 
  </test>
</suite>
```

This gives the following result.

```
DP FIR ----12----1552410839748
DP FIR ----11----1552410839752
DP FIR ----12----1552410843753
DP FIR ----11----1552410843756
DP SEC ----13----1552410847763
DP SEC ----14----1552410847764
DP SEC ----13----1552410851767
DP SEC ----14----1552410851768
DURATION - 16.936 secs
```

The first two rows are started belonging to the dataprovider of the FirstNg class. This is repeated in pairs of two (equals the value of data-provider-thread-count), then the dataprovider of SecondNg class is used.

**Case 2 - Run with thread parallel setting to methods.**

```
<suite name="Surefire suite" data-provider-thread-count="2" parallel="methods"> 
  <test name="Surefire test"> 
    <classes> 
      <class name="testngparallel.FirstNg"/> 
      <class name="testngparallel.SecondNg"/> 
    </classes> 
  </test>
</suite>
```

This gives the following result.

```
DP SEC ----14----1552412828961
DP FIR ----13----1552412828962
DP FIR ----16----1552412828964
DP SEC ----15----1552412828966
DP FIR ----13----1552412832972
DP FIR ----16----1552412832977
DP SEC ----15----1552412832979
DP SEC ----14----1552412832980
DURATION - 8.161 secs
```

The first four rows are started together. Two rows belong to the FirstNg dataprovider and other two belong to the SecondNg. This is repeated till all the rows of all dataproviders are exhausted.

From this discussion it appears there are 2 pools, one for dataprovider and one for other tests - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/BKfSgHoAChU

Adding the parallel="methods" setting, reduces the time of the test execution. Also the sequence of tests are changed, tests from both the dataprovider are mixed up. What is the connection between the two settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Adding the parallel="methods" setting, reduces the time of the test
>   execution. Also the sequence of tests are changed, tests from both the
>   dataprovider are mixed up. What is the connection between the two
>   settings?

Basically the two settings control different execution aspects.
All test methods can be bucketed into two categories.

- Regular test methods
- Test methods that are backed by a data provider.

TestNG has two specific settings to cater to the needs of the above mentioned two categories via

- `thread-count` - which controls at any given point how many regular test methods can run concurrently.
- `data-provider-thread-count` - which controls at any given point, how many data driven test methods can run concurrently.

When you enable both these two settings (and when you have a mix of regular and data driven test methods) what happens is, TestNG runs all the test methods concurrently and amongst them if there are test methods that are data driven in nature, those data driven iterations are executed in parallel as well.

Its like you spinning off a bunch of threads concurrently but one or more of those threads are internally spinning off additional threads.

This setting gives you the maximum throughput in terms of execution speed, but if you have a larger value (obtained by adding both these settings value) you can affect the overall performance, because now the JVM would start doing more context switching instead of scheduling the threads and getting the work done.

The rule of thumb for number of threads in simplistic terms be taken as `2N-1` (where `N` represents the number of cores in your processor. So if you have a quad core processor, your max thread count should be 7).  This is an over-simplistic way of calculating the thread count, but being aware of this has helped me.

Comment: Great info. Thx. Got 2 related queries. Does the `parallel` for regular test setting has precedence over the `parallel` for dataprovider setting when both are used? If there are more than one dataprovider in parallel, then each has a separate thread pool?

Comment: No. There is no precedence or hierarchy associated with these two attributes. And to the second question.. All regular methods share the same thread pool and all data provider methods share the same thread pool. So totally testng has only two thread pools.

Answer (score 1):

To be brief, `parallel = true` to the data provider annotation, allows to use separate thread pool for each iteration of the method with test data regardless of parallel method/class/tests/none.

When you are adding `parallel = true` to the data provider annotation, it will consider a separate pool with size provided using `data-provider-thread-count` (default to 10). So when there is turn of test with data-provider it will executed using separate thread pool in parallel, even if you set `parallel=none` in suite configuration.

**Case `parallel=none` and data-provider `parallel = false` or not set:**
Each method including iterations from data-provider will run in same thread.

```
DP FIR ----1----1552433313814
DP FIR ----1----1552433317824
DP FIR ----1----1552433321834
DP FIR ----1----1552433325839
Normal FIR2 ----1----1552433329848
DP SEC ----1----1552433333855
DP SEC ----1----1552433337859
DP SEC ----1----1552433341865
DP SEC ----1----1552433345871
Normal SEC2 ----1----1552433349876
```

**Case `parallel=none` and data-provider `parallel = true`:**

All methods needs to executed sequentially in same thread accept data-driven methods. If the method is data-driven, when it's turn come, current thread will use separate pool to run each iteration in parallel in case data-provider `parallel = true`. In below execution one data-provider set to `parallel = true` and another not. So you can see the current thread executes iteration in separate pool for "DP FIR" and running all iteration in current thread for "DP SEC". (data-provider-thread-count is not provided hence default to 10)

```
DP FIR ----10----1552433554893
DP FIR ----12----1552433554893
DP FIR ----11----1552433554893
DP FIR ----13----1552433554894
Normal FIR2 ----1----1552433558907
DP SEC ----1----1552433562916
DP SEC ----1----1552433566923
DP SEC ----1----1552433570928
DP SEC ----1----1552433574933
Normal SEC2 ----1----1552433578938
```

```xml
<suite name="suite" >
    <test name="test">
        <classes>
            <class name="FirstNg" />
            <class name="SecondNg" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

```java
public class FirstNg {


    @Test(dataProvider = "dp11", description = "f one")
    public void f11(Integer n, String s) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("DP FIR ----" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "----" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    }

    @Test
    public void f12() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Normal FIR2 ----" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "----" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    }

    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    //@DataProvider
    public Object[][] dp11() {
        return new Object[][] { new Object[] { 1, "a" }, new Object[] { 2, "b" }, new Object[] { 3, "c" },
                new Object[] { 4, "d" } };
    }

}

public class SecondNg {

    @Test(dataProvider = "dp22", description="f two")
    public void f22(Integer n, String s) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("DP SEC ----" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "----" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    }

    @Test
    public void f222() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Normal SEC2 ----" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "----" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    }

    //@DataProvider(parallel = true)
    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] dp22() {
        return new Object[][] { new Object[] { 1, "a" }, new Object[] { 2, "b" }, new Object[] { 3, "c" },
                new Object[] { 4, "d" }};
    }       
}
```

**Case `parallel=methods or classes`:**

With `parallel=methods` It will start executing in parallel, depending with pool of size provided by `thread-count` in xml configuration. Again If the method is data-driven, when it's turn come, allocated thread will run each iteration in parallel separate pool. Otherwise allocated thread run each iteration in sequence.

You can see the thread assigned to  "DP FIR" executes iteration in separate pool for "DP FIR" but running all iteration in assigned thread for "DP SEC".

```
DP FIR ----14----1552433989613
Normal FIR2 ----11----1552433989614
DP FIR ----17----1552433989613
DP SEC ----12----1552433989613
DP FIR ----16----1552433989613
DP FIR ----15----1552433989616
Normal SEC2 ----13----1552433989617
DP SEC ----12----1552433993625
DP SEC ----12----1552433997632
DP SEC ----12----1552434001640
```

**Case `parallel=methods or classes` and data-provider `parallel = false` or not set:**

when turn of data-driven method come, each iteration will executed in sequence in allocated thread.